# how to split the words from specified string in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a string `getallairlinedetails`. There is no space nor any delimiter between the specified string. How can i split this string like  this :"get all airline details"

Comment: I don't see any pattern to split it.

Comment: is there any possible way by which i can get words from this string like airline or get

Comment: Take a look at `String.Split` overloads or other `String` methods anyway..

Comment: Thanks all for ur reply..

Comment: You have to define the input of your algorithm, is it any string (if so, what should it do with "sofjsdoifjsd") ? Is it any English sentence with space removed ? Is it a grammar containing a finite set of ressources and actions ?

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no evident pattern for splitting here, there is no **reliable** way for you to do it.

But if set of your words to spilt is not very large - you can try to create some dictionary and then split using this dictionary.

You can try to replace in your string for each word from dictionary

```
word_from_dictionary => " " + word_from_dictionary + " "
```

and split resulting string by `String.Split` using space as delimiter.

For example, let your dictionary contains words "get", "all" and "details".

Then by replacing all words from dictionary you will get `get  all airline details` - this can be splitted.

Of course this is not a very reliable way since it depends on dictionary you need to somehow populate.

Comment: Also if the dictionary contains both 'airline' and 'air', then you don't want to split "airline".

Comment: @HansKesting Surely. Actually it was implied in "*is it not very reliable way since it depends on dictionary*" too... Thanks for accenting this issue.

Comment: Given that in general it is a bad idea, I'm not sure it would be a good idea using `Contains` as you suggest instead of trying to find words from left to right and stopping when you don't find one word... Clearly in this way you'll need a full dictionary, and not a partial dictionary as you suggested. So given the words `get  all airline` and the sentence `getallairlinedetails` you begin looking using `StartsWith` and then remove the found word.

Comment: You find that the sentence begins with `get`. You remove `get` and have `allairlinedetails`... you find `all` and `airlinedetails` remains. You find `airline` and you remove it. `details` remain. You don't find it and you consider it to be a full word, returning it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static List<string> Dict = new List<string> { "details", "airline", "all", "get" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String s = "getallairlinedetails";

        Console.WriteLine(ReturnSplitString(s));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string ReturnSplitString(string s)
    {
        string[] ww = new string[s.Length];

        foreach (string word in Dict)
        {
            if (s.Contains(word))
            {
                int ind = s.IndexOf(word);
                ww[ind] = word;
            }
        }

        string sf = "";

        foreach (string sr in ww)
        {
            if (sr != null)
                sf += sr + " ";
        }

        return sf.TrimEnd(' ');
    }
```

something like this would be your only bet, iterate through a dictionary containing the individual words, store them by their location in the string, and then join the array up at the end in order.

this code returns correctly by the way, just changing `s` and adding any words to the dictionary will return for different words.

there is no way to do this without at least knowing what you're searching for though is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. The Split method requires at least one character, like white space, in order to split the string. Otherwise, there isn't any criteria on which the split of the string to an array of substrings will be based on.

Think about the problem, before you try to pick a type's method to solve it. How would you split this string? What would be your algorithm?

Thinking about the latter, very soon you will realize that you simply can't split it, because you don't have anything that you could rely on.

For instance, in your case, if the string was like this:

```
"get_all_airline_details"
```

it would have been clear that all the words are separated from one another with a `_`. Hence, starting from left to right, you will find the end of the first word at the first `_`. Then the second word would start after this `_` and will end at the second `_` and so on and so forth.

Of course this is thought that you will make when you will notice this string. If you want to split it in c#, you could use the string's split method passing this character `_`. However the takeaway of the above is the fact that we should first find a "pattern" and then try to split the string. Then which language you will use to do so, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Its seems to be a comment

Comment: @SaiKalyanKumarAkshinthala This was my first thought. However, I thinked it again and I realized that this is the only answer that can be given to this question.

Comment: Is there any way by which i can get the words from this string like:get

Comment: Since there isn't any pattern, as already correctly Soner pointed out in his comment, you can't.